# Modifying service control permissions in a Windows MSI installer

Tags: service, permissions, controls, windows-installer, servicecontroller

So right now I'm trying to change permissions on a windows service by using the command: sc sdset SERVICENAME PERMISSIONS

I have placed this in an MSI installer as an action and it seems to execute fine. However, sc requires administrator privlidges to set the permissions and I cannot seem to find a way to do that within the MSI installer. I tried using the command runas /user:administrator but unfortunatley this could be different on the machines the installer is going to run on.

Any tips?

Comment: What are you using to create your MSI? WiX has some functionality in it's Util extension which is helpful here.  I've been known to make merge modules to encapsulate the logic then merge it into InstallShield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a custom action with full privileges you can mark it as deferred with no impersonation. This is done differently in each setup authoring tool, so you need to be more specific about what you are using if you want more details.

The basic settings are:

- schedule the custom action between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize actions in [InstallExecuteSequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) table
- set [msidbCustomActionTypeInScript and msidbCustomActionTypeNoImpersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368069%28VS.85%29.aspx) flags in Type column from [CustomAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368062%28VS.85%29.aspx) table

This way your custom action will run under the local SYSTEM account with full privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Windows Installer 5.0, you can also use the MsiLockPermissionsEx table. In WiX that would for example look like this:

```
<ServiceInstall Name="Your Service Name" ErrorControl="normal" Start="demand" Type="ownProcess">
  <PermissionEx Sddl="long ugly SDDL string" />
</ServiceInstall>
```

This creates a service with the correct permissions for me. It should also take care of admin privileges, though I haven't tested a standalone installer with just the service. See also:

- https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/xsd/wix/permissionex/ (as you can see, PermissionEx admits a parent of ServiceInstall)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/msilockpermissionsex-table (here is where your service permissions will end up - check with Orca or so)